# Spears and fears

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> Trepidation fell on such sight
> Cry without knowing why
> I'm without me myself, flanked by similarly selfish beings.
> Vulgar as it may sound—the end concerns your backside,
> stripped of its opening.
> Let spears bury unto you, the face of evil.

#### What is it that I talk of?

Comment: @shivsn if you have an idea, please write it in as an answer and not in comments.

Comment: Is it a single word or a combination of two words.. I thought of *hum-bum*... based on the hint.

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay It's one word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be referring to the act of

> [Impalement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impalement) of CRIMINALs

We can build one of these words from the puzzle

`Cry without knowing why`

> Remove Y ("why") from CRY, we get CR

`I'm without me myself, flanked by similarly selfish beings.`

> Remove I (me myself) from I'M, to get M.
>  Then flank it with the letter I (selfish beings) to get IMI.

`Vulgar as it may sound—the end concerns your backside, stripped of its opening.`

> Take away the first letter (strip the opening) from ANAL, which means "concerns your backside". We get NAL.

Put the pieces together to get

> CR+IMI+NAL

Regarding the first and last lines

> Impalement is a form of capital punishment, using spears to execute criminals (which also concerns their backsides!). This also instills fear in your enemies. [Vlad the Impaler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vlad_the_Impaler) was notorious for this practice.

Comment: The OP said in a comment that the solution is one word only...

Comment: @MikeQ That's exactly what I was aiming for! +1 I'm aware that the clues were quite obscure, and I wasn't much hopeful someone would eventually solve it. So, kudos!

Comment: @MikeQ I updated the last line to make the answer more obvious.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure this is a longshot, however are you talking about

> A longbow?

Trepidation fell on such sight

> People on the opposite side of the archers will be afraid of seeing a line of archers aiming at them.

Cry without knowing why

> I am not pretty sure right now how to interpret this clue yet

I'm without me myself, flanked by similarly selfish beings.

> The two ends of the longbow are tied with the string, they look like they both wants the string to themself (selfish?), also "One of the simpler longbow designs is known as the self bow"

The end concerns your backside, stripped of its opening.

> When you grab the arrow to the back and release it. Stripping the bow of it's initial state?

Vulgar as it may sound

> It's used for killing, or hunting.

Let spears bury unto you, those of brits.

> Not sure if spears here means arrows, and those of brits means that the longbow is known for the Medieval Brittish soldiers?

Comment: No, this isn't the answer I was looking for. I updated a few lines to make it more clear. Wordplay is involved---don't parse the clues literally.

Comment: It was worth a shot, I am not a native english speaker, so sometimes it's hard for me to get it right in a wordplay! But it's fun to try my luck :D

Comment: I understand your misery---I'm a non-native English speaker too! :-)

Comment: Judging from your name, you seem to be an Indian.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that my name could be mislead to be an Indian! That's new for me. I am actually Lebanese, and I don't hide that in my profile ;)